# How to check session in Laravel in web.php for Route::post('/url', 'controllername@methodname')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.6

I am trying to do is that if a user is not logged in and trying to enter addPost in the url in addressbar of chrome like www.siteurl/addPost and searching for it then user should redirected to LoginPage.blade.php which is in my views folder. But it throws an *error*: **MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message**
I tried a lot but unable to find where I am doing wrong. Can anybody help me out. Thank you in advance.
[image]

A.This is my **view(Addpost.blde.php)**:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('/addPost')}}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title" />    
    <textarea name="post_description" id="post_description" ></textarea>  
    <button type="submit" name="post">Post</button>
</form>
```

B.This is my **route(web.php)**:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkuser'], function () {
            Route::post('/addPost', 'PostsController@addNewPost');

});
Route::get('/LoginPage', function () {
    return view('LoginPage');
});
```

C.This is **addNewPost function in PostsController**:

```
  public function addNewPost(Request $request){
    $userid = Session::get('id');       
     $post_title = $request->input('post_title');
     $post_description = $request->input('post_description');
$addPostintoDB = new MyPostsModel(['user_id' => $userid, 'post_title'=> $post_title, 'post_description'=> $post_description]);
    $addPostintoDB->save();
echo "post saved";
}
```

D.This is my **custom middleware**:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Session;
class CheckUser
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      if (!Session::get('id')) {
          return redirect('/LoginPage');
      }
   return $next($request);
  }
}
```

E.Added this to **Kernel.php** in the $routeMiddleware property array:

```
'checkuser' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUser::class,
```

Comment: You're sending a 'GET' request by directly entering the url in the browser, hence the 405 exception.

Comment: You are trying to 'GET' request a 'POST' route!

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkuser'], function () {
    Route::get('/addPost', 'PostsController@createPost');
    Route::post('/addPost', 'PostsController@addNewPost');
});
```

This method in your controller

```
public function createPost()
{
    // this is method to show your Addpost.blade.php file
    return view('Addpost');
}
```

And don't forget to add this inside your `<form>` tag

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: You missed the `Route::get()` method in the first time, that's why MethodNotAllowed Error is showed.